# Add parameter to securesocial custom view (playframework)

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, securesocial

I am using playframework with securesocial and I am also using securesocial [custom views](http://securesocial.ws/guide/views-customization.html).

Right now, I need to pass an additional parameter to my login custom view, which determine whenever some content should be hidden or not.

```
  override def getLoginPage[A](implicit request: Request[A], form: Form[(String, String), additionalParam: Boolean],
                               msg: Option[String] = None): Html =
  {
    dentfliks.views.html.login(form, msg, additionalParam)
  }
```

Is there any way do it without change securesocial implementation?

My custom view

```
@(loginForm: play.api.data.Form[(String,String)], errorMsg: Option[String] = None, additionalParam: Boolean)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader, lang: Lang)

<html>
(...)
</html>
```

Using the source bellow I get the following error...

```
class CustomSecureSocialViews needs to be abstract, since method getLoginPage in trait TemplatesPlugin of type [A](implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request[A], implicit form: play.api.data.Form[(String, String)], implicit msg: Option[String])play.api.templates.Html is not defined
```

Note that I am using play 2.2.2.

Comment: But how can you pass that additional parameter when SecureSocial is calling it behind the scenes?